# Common lib on symfony2

Tags: php, symfony

Before using Symfony2, I used to have a common lib with a lot of simple but useful functions (for instance, a function which takes "Azè_rtï" in argument and returns "aze-rti").

So, well, I created a Bundle: CommonLibsBundle.

But.. I have only one or two php files. It does not make sense to me to use a controller / view / model in this kind of situation.
What should  I do? May I erase all folders in my new bundle (Controller, DependencyInjection, Resources, Tests... + CommonLibsBundle.php) and just put my lib.php in it?

Many thanks,
Bliss

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you need to tap into the Symfony framework itself - for configuration or to define services, it doesn't need to be a bundle - it's just a library. Give it a reasonable namespace, and call as required as you would any other component or library.

Even if you wanted to add Symfony-specific services that you could call, there is something to be said to still have an external simple library - usable anywhere, which then is wrapped by a very thin bundle which would only add the Symfony-specific (or Laravel, or ZF, or whatever) services and configuration as required.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback! For information, I also found this link very useful: http://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices/business-logic.html